# rpart and rpart2

Tags: machine-learning, r

I'm not sure if this is more appropriate for SO or DS in Stack Exchange since technically it's not about coding: in `caret` package for training in R, it's possible to train the model using `rpart` or `rpart2` as the method.

I understand that `rpart` is an implementation of CART. What is `rpart2` and how is it different from `rpart`?

My eventual aim is actually to compare the difference between the tree generated by `rpart` and `rpart2`, because my result seems to imply `rpart2` has better accuracy for my dataset, but I have no clue how to view the `rpart2` tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `rpart` and `rpart2` implement a CART and wrap the `rpart` function from the **rpart** library.  The difference is the constraints on the model each enforces.  `rpart` uses the complexity parameter, `cp`, while `rpart2` uses the max tree depth, `maxdepth`.

See: `train_model_list` section of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf  and `rpart.control` section of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I belatedly found out also that the answer to the portion "but I have no clue how to view the rpart2 tree." is to view the `finalModel` element in the output of `rpart2` trained with `caret`.